# Response.Redirect() not working after javascript confirm got false value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, redirect, confirm

I had a simple page like this:

A.aspx -
has an asp TabControl make user change to B.aspx or back, and a button will use javascript confirm user to do something.

B.aspx -
has the same TabControl like A.aspx , just show some message here.

button code in A.aspx like this:

```
<button id="do" onclick="if (confirm('you sure?')==false) { return false; };"></button>
```

and my Response.Redirect code in A.aspx.cs TabControl_TabChanged() like this:

```
Response.Redirect("b.aspx");
```

It work fine before I click the button, if I click it and select 'ok' it still fine,
but when I select 'cancel', the Response.Redirect() will run but the page didn't change.
please help me find the problem.

Comment: How do you know that Response.Redirect executes? It sounds like you've got a normal http-post from your button, but missing the asp.net postback parameters required for the controls to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to set a jQuery event on my Button

```
<form id="submitform">
 <button id="do" >change</button>
</form>

 $("#do").click(function(e) {
  var r=confirm("you sure?");
       if (r===false)
       {
          e.preventDefault();
       }
 });
```

perhaps this helps

Comment: I found that problem is on a 3rd-party lib, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace 'onclick' for javascript with 'OnClientClick'.

Comment: If you just replace onclick="if (confirm('you sure?')==false) { return false; };"    this with onClientClick="if (confirm('you sure?')==false) { return false; };"   and onclick event will of server side post back event of button clicking